# Debug Executed Sql in Python

Tags: python, sql

I am executing some sql in python as follows

```
statement = "select * from TEST_TABLE"
debug("Statement: %s" % (statement, ))
cursor = gblDBConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement)
```

I can debug the statement using a debug function I have written but would also like to debug the actual values returned ie after sql execution.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
statement = "select * from TEST_TABLE"
cursor = gblDBConnection.cursor()
values = cursor.execute(statement)
debug(values)
```

?